# Show image from another model using id upload by paperclip Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view, model, paperclip

How do I access Image.photo using its id from Pin models view?

Currently I am doing this and it gives me random number if I remove the image_tag or bank image space.

```
<td><%= image_tag Image.find_by_id(pin.pic) %></td>
```

This one gives me undefined method `photo' for nil:NilClass

```
<td><%= image_tag Image.find_by_id(pin.pic).photo.url(:small) %></td>


class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :board, :pic, :pin_time, :user, :apic, :photo
  belongs_to :auser, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'user' 
  belongs_to :apic,   :class_name => 'Image',:foreign_key => 'pic'
end


class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :uid, :web_url, :photo, :photo_file_name,:photo_content_type, :photo_file_size, :photo_updated_at, :id
  has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :small => "150x150>", :medium => "300x300", :large => "600x600"}

  belongs_to :user

  validates_attachment_presence :photo
  validates_attachment_size :photo, :less_than => 5.megabytes
  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']
end
```

Comment: Have you tried logging into your s3 account with something like this: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/amazon-s3-organizers3fox/ and checking if the file is there?

Comment: Its not loading to amazon. Its loading it locally and yes the files do exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply

```
pin.apic.photo.url(:small)
```

Or are you looking for something else completely?

Comment: undefined method `photo' for nil:NilClass

Comment: so pin.apic is Nil, meaning that this pin has no pics or your associations are broken. How do you add images to pins? Can you check in console that pin.apic exists for the given pin? If apic is optional, you should probably use (pin.apic.photo.url if pin.apic)